# how to insert a column with value row number in an access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large access table . I need to have a column which will have value as row number
how can I write an sql query fill an empty column inserted by me with row numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a sequence for your table . Then have default value as  sequence .

So, whenever the column does not get users values , it will take the sequence values.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, im a little confused at what you're getting at, but could you not just do an alter table?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
 ADD row_number  int;
```

Comment: the value of fields should be equal to corresponding row number not blank

Comment: An Autonumber field will be populated when it's created. However, the resulting ordering may not be exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Field DataType AutoNumber it will do it for you automatically.

Comment: no once the data is entered in the table the new field cant be set to autoincrement ..